# Pen tool does not work in vectorizing a photo in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am an starter. I want to vectorize a photo in illustrator. I place it, activate the layer panel, choose pen tool. But nothing happens. Pen tool does not draw anything on the photo layer. When I use the pencil tool instead, there is no line on the new white layer.Can anybody help me find the way? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drawing-pen-curvature-or-pencil.html I assure you the Pen tool works, thousands use it daily. So there must be something you are doing which you are unaware of.

Comment: have you tried check if the layer is a template layer? sometimes the template layer is locked and the pen tool might not work. Can you share a screenshot of the layers panel. might give a better idea to what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. Thanks.